# JFrameアプリケーションに隙間ができる

Tags: java, swing

Javaで、JFrameを使って2Dゲームを作っているのですが、起動すると、画像のようにたまに右端と下に謎の隙間ができてしまいます。

Layoutをいじってみてもあまり効果がありませんでした。

起動する時によって隙間が出来る時と出来ない時があります。この隙間を出てこなくするにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。知っている方がいらっしゃいましたら是非ご教授ください。
[image: 右と下に隙間が出来ている様子]

**追記**

OSはWindows 7
Javaのバージョンは"1.8.0_91"
下記のソースコードでも同様の現象がみられました。

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Test(){
        Container cnt = getContentPane();
        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();
        setResizable(false);
        cnt.add(panel);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setVisible(true);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class MainPanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public MainPanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

[image: 下記ソースコード]

Comment: 同じサイズを設定しているのに1回目と2回目の表示でサイズが異なる、というバグが報告されていますね(ただしこのレポートが言うにはWindows7では発生しないようですが)。実行環境の情報(OS/Javaバージョン)や再現可能なコードを追記されると、回答が得られやすくなるかと思います。 https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8073710 / http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8079253

Comment: 追記でペーストしたコードは本当にそのままですか？(2行目が、finallongってなっててそのままではコンパイルしないと思うんですが)

Comment: 失礼しました。final longでした。

Comment: 自分の場合`setResizable(false);`をJFrameを作って一番最初に持ってくると治ったのですが、それはもともと`pack();`より後にやってたからだったので治らないかもしれないですが、どうでしょう

Comment: やってみましたが、やはり隙間が出来てしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

以下で引用している`Swing`のチュートリアルに記述されているように、イベント・ディスパッチ・スレッド(`EDT`)内で`Swing`オブジェクトのメソッドを呼ぶというルールを無視していると、たまに変な挙動(`JFrame`のサイズが0になったり、表示位置がズレたりなど)をしたり、再現不可なエラーが発生したりします。

[Lesson: Concurrency in Swing (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

> #### The Event Dispatch Thread
>
> Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event dispatch thread. Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are not "thread safe": invoking them from multiple threads risks thread interference or memory consistency errors. Some Swing component methods are labelled "thread safe" in the API specification; these can be safely invoked from any thread. All other Swing component methods must be invoked from the event dispatch thread. Programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.

今回の現象もこれが原因の可能性が高そうなので、上記チュートリアルの左にある目次の[Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)にあるように、[SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-)などで、`JFrame#pack()`や`JFrame#setVisible()`などの`Swing`メソッドを呼ぶタスクをスケジュールし、`EDT`内で実行することで回避できそうな気がします。

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final int WIDTH = 500;
  private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

  public MainPanel() {
    super();
    //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
  }
  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }
}
```